# React Router v4 not working after Webpack build

Tags: reactjs, webpack-2, react-router-v4

I am trying to serve my "React App build" with a simple python server but routing is not working:

> Error code 404.
>
> Message: File not found.
>
> Error code explanation: 404 = Nothing matches the given URI.

Which is the good way to setup routing with React router v4 in order for the built version to work?

It works well with the Webpack dev server but as soon as I try to build it with webpack (`webpack`), then the routing stops working.

Do I need to provide special flags to Webpack in order for the routing to work after build?

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import {createBrowserHistory} from 'history';

...
let browserHistory = createBrowserHistory({});

...
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <div>
    <App />

    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/workflow" render={
        () => (
          <Workflow
            components={components}
            models={models}
            patient={patient}
            steps={steps}/>) } />
  </div>
</Router>
```

Thanks

Comment: I haven't had any issues with getting react router v4 to work with webpack, didn't have to do anything. Have you tried using the Webpack Dev Server, to see if it is just configuration of the Python server that is failing?

Comment: Yes Webpack Dev Server works well, problem is after build, I'd like the build to just work out of the box with 0 server configuration

Comment: Are you saying that it works with the webpack dev server... and that it doesn't work with your python server?

Comment: Yes exactly. I'd like the build version to work out of the box without any server configuration required -

Comment: That is difficult because every server has different configuration - you're trying to rely on every web server being configured out of the box with everything you need. Usually people create installers or scripts that get the web server configured with exactly what the app needs in order to be run...